# Query about useEffect hook in React

Tags: reactjs

So I was watching this yt video that explains how useRef works and there was this piece of code that was at the end of the video that puzzles me (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2ypzz6gJm0)

It basically uses a `useRef` to tell u what u **previously** typed in the textbox and what is currently typed into the textbox, but I dont understand why it works:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const prevName = useRef("");
  useEffect(() => {
    prevName.current = name;
  }, [name]);
  return (
    <>
      <input value={name} onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
      <div>
        {" "}
        my name is {name} and it used to be {prevName.current}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

So My understanding of how `useEffect` works is that it will only apply the `useEffect` function ***after*** a re-render of the component. So according to this logic, the value of `name` will already change to it's most recent value (i.e. whats currently in the input textbox) when the `useEffect` function is called.

So why is this logic wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So My understanding of how useEffect works is that it will only apply the useEffect function after a re-render of the component.

Correct

> So according to this logic, the value of name will already change to it's most recent value (i.e. whats currently in the input textbox) when the useEffect function is called.

Also correct.

But the useEffect isn't trying to change what happens on the current render. It's purpose is just to set things up for the *next* time the component renders. While the render is happening, the effect has not yet run, and so `prevName.current` contains an old value (which is what we want). Only once rendering is complete does the effect run and change `prevName.current`. This is too late to mess up the current render, but it can be used on the next render.

Comment: Ohhhh I think my whole misunderstanding is that I thought that when the `useEffect`  is performed, it will trigger a re-render. but obviously it doesen't since we are changing a `useRef` object which doesent trigger a re-render. Ironic, considering that kinda the whole point of `useRef` is that it doesent trigger a re-render. Thanks for the helpful answer :)